# new Intent loading wrong xml files

Tags: android, xml, android-intent, spinner

I noticed today in one of my apps that when I loaded a new Intent for a certain few classes(these classes are determined from the click of an object on a Spinner), the layouts appear and they are like the original plain layouts I started with in my project, not the ones I updated and changed to make look better.

I checked all my code and everything, there are no xml files for what it's loading(they are old ones that I had used before). I don't understand why these old, non existing xml files are even loading. It should be loading the current ones I have in my project but it doesn't... Can someone help me with this problem? Thanks

Comment: The IDE you are using might be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using eclipse, you can try doing `Project > Clean`, and then `Refresh` your project.  This should make sure you are building with the latest resources.

Comment: Well the thing is, it works on my Emulator. but I was using my dads phone (he downloaded it from the Android market) and thats where I found the problem. I have no clue what's causing it

Comment: Maybe you just need to clean/refresh, then export signed application, and try updating your app on Android Market.  It might be worth doing an `adb install <your_generated_AND_signed>.apk` to install manually onto your device before publishing to Android Market.